# Calling rails api through curl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, curl, afnetworking

I have a Rails application that my mobile app is trying to call. I tried testing the API through curl with the following command and it works.

```
curl -d "user[name]=bob&user[email]=bob0814@example.com&user[password]=password&user[company_name]=hydra" linktomyapi
```

Now, I tried running the following command because when I send parameters through mobile app, I send them as a JSON format since I use **AFNetworking** for all my Networking calls, see below and this doesn't work.

```
curl -v -d '{"user[name]": "bob","user[email]": "bob@gmail.com","user[password]": "password","user[company_name]": "rs"}' linktoMyApi
```

I am quite confused as to why this difference is? Could anyone suggest any ideas?

Comment: Have you specified that the format is json? What is the error message you are getting?

Comment: Its says 400 - Bad request. I made similar kind of all before for another View in my iOS app and that worked just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pass an application/json Content-Type so rails can understand you are speaking json.

Add to your curl options : `-H 'Content-Type:application/json'`

Additionnaly, if you want to access your params with `params[:user]`, you have to use a json object "user" to hold all the values :

```
{"user" : {"name": "bob", "email": "bob@gmail.com", "password": "password", "company_name": "rs"}}
```

Comment: I still get the same error. Thank you for the response though.

Comment: Can you paste the rails server log so we can understand what's happening ?

Comment: Looks like it's working. Let me do couple of more tests and I will close this question.